# Stretch video more than screen size

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I use MediaPlayer to display video.
The problem is, if I stretch the video to fit the screen size, the new aspect ratio is different than the original aspect ratio of the video. Thus, the video looks ugly.
This is because the original aspect ratio of the video is iPad 2.

My question is is it possible to stretch the video beyond the screen size and then "crop" it to resize it to the screen size. Doing this will maintain the original aspect ratio.

In iOS, I think, it is called Scaling Mode Aspect Fill.

Comment: Have you tried `mediaPlayer.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`?  I'm not familiar with the Media Player framework but you may be able to set the content mode of its view.

Comment: @MattLogan You gave an iOS answer to an Android question.

Comment: @Muz How are you scaling the video now? It is definitely possible, but I'd have to know what you're doing to let you know where you're going wrong.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this? I'm having a similar problem. I'm doing moviePlayer.view.frame = view.bounds; moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill but the player won't even expand to the bounds of iphone 6 nor 6+...